# How to store select information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am a bit unsure on how to store the data from a collection_tag.

Here the model I am working on

```
Customer         GenderManager      Genders
Id               Id                 Id
First            Customer_id        Description
Last             Gender_id
Email            Created_at
Password
```

Here the relationship

```
Customer::class
  has_many :gender_managers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gender_managers, allow_destroy: :true
Gender::class
  has_many :gender_managers
GenderManagers:class
  belongs_to :customer_id
  belongs_to :gender_id
```

The form I have currently his has follow

```
 <%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
    <div class="customer_edit_error_message">
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
    <div class="customer_edit_name">
            <%= f.label :first_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="customer_edit_middle_name">
            <%= f.label :middle_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :middle_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="customer_edit_last_name">
            <%= f.label :last_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="customer_edit_gender">
    <%= f.collection_select(:customer, :id, Gender.all, :id, :description) %>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_edit_button">
            <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "button_accept" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

In customerController not sure if I must do something. I know its not right its giving me errors. Its the form that worry me on the select like

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your view code suggest a different relationship, namely `Customer belongs_to :gender`. You mean you want to store whether a customer is male or female?

Comment: Yes but maybe keep track of the change :D

Comment: What do you mean "keep track of the change"? Someone changing gender is very rare and why would you want to keep track of that. I don't think you need `GenderManager` and to be honest you don't need `Gender` either. Just add a field `gender` to your `Customer` model and you're done. There will always be male and female, no need to store that in a table.

Comment: Well it does occurs, rarely i admit, but the app i want to implement needs to keep track of everything, not just gender, but bod, many other options. Should I use a fields_for then place my collection_select in it?

Comment: Well someone can only have one gender at a time, so you could add something like `GenderHistory` to keep track of the changes. And `current_gender` in your `Customer` model. I don't think you need `Gemders`, `GenderManager` or `fields_for`.

Comment: Okay that make sense, how would i update gender history if change occurs?

Comment: You can add a `before_update` [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview) in your `Customer` model that checks whether there is a change in `current_gender` and if so add a new record to `GenderHistory`.

Comment: How do I add a new record while in a model function?

Comment: The same way as in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you add an attribute `gender` to your `Customer` model. If you want to keep track of changes you can create a `GenderHistory` model and do something like this in `Customer`:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gender_histories
  before_update :track_gender

  def track_gender
    self.gender_histories.create(:gender => self.gender) if self.gender_changed?
  end
end
```

Your `Genders` and `GenderManager` models are not necessary.